# I can't check my android app on my mobile?

Tags: android

I am using android version 2.3.6 using Huawei U8650 I have installed hisuite but when I connect my mobile with computer it says on hisuite home menu "Not connected". However my mobile is connected properly and there's no problem with the cable also. It works on the other phone. Usb debugger mode is also checked..!

Comment: Already lot of such a questions available.

Comment: I have checked some but couldn't solve the issue... kindly tell me the link if it solves the issue